# Luis.ai synonyms in prebuilt geography entity

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using the prebuilt entity Geography in LUIS.AI
It identifies "USA", "United States", "America" as of type geography. How do i group them all under one canonical name (ex: "United States")?

Answer (score 0):

If using the `builtin.geography.country` entity, I don't think we're able to modify the values of this built-in entity.

If you want to group ""USA", "United States" and "America" under one canonical form, you can refer to [List entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-entities#list-entities), create your own entity for it for example like this:

[image]